# Unable to connect to MongoDB in robotframework

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

I have installed the libraries

```
robotframework-MongoDBLibrary >=0.3.4
pymongo >=3.10.1
bson >=0.5.9
```

And the robot script is

```
*** Variables ***
${MDBHost}        localhost
${MDBPort}        ${52010}

*** Test Cases ***
Connect-Disconnect
    [Tags]    regression
    Comment    Connect to MongoDB Server
    Connect To MongoDB    ${MDBHost}    ${MDBPort}
    Comment    Disconnect from MongoDB Server
    Disconnect From MongoDB
```

When I try to execute it gives me an error like

> Importing test library 'MongoDBLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mongo_connection_manager'

Comment: Have you installed pymongo library which is a base module for this robot framework mongodb library ?

Comment: Hi @SariqShaikh, Yes I have installed pymongo library `pymongo >=3.10.1`

Comment: I ran into the same issue and it looks like there are two very similar looking libraries; robotframework-mongodblibrary and robotframework-mongodb-library

After uninstalling the first one and installing the second, things were okay. :S